# Android studio gives me error

Tags: android, android-studio

(this is on ask ubuntu due to it being installed on a ubuntu system, I think it would make a difference.)

Ok. I just installed Android Studio, and I was excited to start testing it out, then, I ran the default program, and it gave me the following:

```
Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '/home/zorin/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (341ms)
```

Im looking for a solution, if you know how, please help me!

I would deeply appreciate it!

Comment: What does the IDE log show?

Comment: How do I get to ide log?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Not sure how

Comment: It sounds like you didn't select the correct Java version in Android Studio. Try to install Oracle JDK 8 and set it to be used by Android Studio from its settings.